# Having a limit in sqlite3 with one or two digits python

Tags: python, sqlite, limits

The problem is that when the input(the limit) is a two digit number it gives an error. "Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied." I have tried to make it an integer but then SQLite3 requires string. If I define a constant it still doesn't work. But if it is a one digit number it works.

```
limit = input("Enter the number of scores you want to see: ")
self.cursor.execute('SELECT Name, Gender, Age, Score, Date, Time FROM Link JOIN Scores ON  Score_ID = Scores.ID JOIN Player ON Player_ID = Player.id ORDER BY Score DESC LIMIT ?', (limit))
```

Comment: Are you running this inside of a class? the `self` passes the instance of itself to the call, hence you are providing 2 parameters instead of 1 to execute method.

Comment: yes it's an OOP program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter to [`.execute()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) needs to be a sequence. For example, you could pass a `list` or a `tuple`. Here is how to make it a tuple:

```
self.cursor.execute(
    'SELECT Name, Gender, Age, Score, Date, Time FROM Link JOIN Scores ON  Score_ID = Scores.ID JOIN Player ON Player_ID = Player.id ORDER BY Score DESC LIMIT ?',
    (limit,))
```

Here is how to make it a list:

```
self.cursor.execute(
    'SELECT Name, Gender, Age, Score, Date, Time FROM Link JOIN Scores ON  Score_ID = Scores.ID JOIN Player ON Player_ID = Player.id ORDER BY Score DESC LIMIT ?',
    [limit])
```

Notes:

- The reason that `limit='9'` works, but `limit='10'` fails is that a string is also sequence. The elements of the sequence are the 1-character strings that make up the larger string. So in the first case, you pass the single parameter `'9'`. In the second, you pass the two parameters, `'1'` and `'0'`.
- The reason that `(limit)` fails but `(limit,)` succeeds has to do with a quirk of the Python syntax. Parentheses `()` are used both for expression grouping and for tuple creation. `(obj)` is simply the object `obj` itself. `(obj,)` on the other hand, is a one-member `tuple`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and very very nice explanation. Now it works